Practica metabacording DADA2 Rstudio
Me sale una erro tipo; Error en fls[[i]]: this S4 class is not subsettable

intento hacer una Tabla de abundancias con un archivo fastaq pero no sale la matriz de errores entonces primero quiero hacer eso, no se mucho de programación en R y me sale ese error mi código es.

# Cargar las librerías necesarias
library(dada2)

# Ruta al archivo filtrado
archivo_filtrado <- "C:/Users/jerem/Desktop/Nueva carpeta/filtered/Initial.fastq"

num_lecturas <- length(sread(readFastq(archivo_filtrado)))
print(num_lecturas) 

library(ShortRead)

# Cargar el archivo FASTQ
qfile <- readFastq("C:/Users/jerem/Desktop/Nueva carpeta/filtered/Initial.fastq")

# Obtener las calidades
qual_matrix <- quality(qfile)

# Convertir el objeto 'FastqQuality' a una matriz numérica
qual_matrix_numeric <- as(qual_matrix, "matrix")

# Calcular el promedio de calidad por base
mean_quality <- rowMeans(qual_matrix_numeric)

# Visualizar las primeras 10 calidades promedio
print(mean_quality[1:10])

# Visualizar el gráfico de calidad promedio por base
plot(mean_quality, type = "l", col = "blue", main = "Promedio de calidad por base", xlab = "Posición de la base", ylab = "Calidad promedio")

# Filtrar y truncar las lecturas a la posición deseada (ajustar según tu gráfico de calidad)
resultado_filtrado <- filterAndTrim(
  archivos_fastq,        # Ruta a los archivos de entrada
  archivos_filtrados,    # Ruta a los archivos de salida
  truncLen = 130,        # Truncar las lecturas a la posición 130 (ajustar según la calidad)
  maxN = 1,              # No se permiten Ns en las secuencias
  maxEE = 5,             # Umbral de errores esperados
  truncQ = 0,            # Umbral de calidad para truncado
  rm.phix = FALSE,       # Eliminar contaminantes PhiX
  compress = TRUE,       # Comprimir los archivos filtrados
  multithread = FALSE    # Cambiado a FALSE para compatibilidad con Windows
)

# Definir la ruta del archivo FASTQ
archivo_fastq <- "C:/Users/jerem/Desktop/Nueva carpeta/filtered/Initial.fastq"

# Leer el archivo FASTQ (limitar a 1000 lecturas para evitar problemas)
qfile <- readFastq(archivo_fastq, n = 1000)

# Ver las primeras lecturas para asegurarnos de que se cargaron correctamente
head(qfile)

# Calcular la matriz de errores con las lecturas leídas
err <- learnErrors(qfile, multithread = FALSE)

# Ver la matriz de errores para comprobar que se calculó correctamente
print(err)

# Inferir las secuencias con la matriz de errores calculada
dada_obj <- dada(qfile, err = err, multithread = FALSE)

# Ver el resultado de las secuencias inferidas
print(dada_obj)

quería ver si podía conseguir la matriz de errores

This side is English only. Please [edit] your question and translate it into English.

Also this is tagged as java but the code is no java.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ https://es.stackoverflow.com/
